# Is there a package for show equation's name references?

Tags: cross-referencing, draft

I'm writing my thesis so I have too many references to handle. When I print a draft I'd like to have a "verbatim style" name (`\label{eq:blabla}` or `\ref{eq:blabla}`) for reference instead a number.
 Does anyone know a package to do that without writing in the text (or conditional compilation)?

Thank you.

Comment: I would probably want to have the name written in the margin instead but that's just me...

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys?

Comment: Why don't you formulate an answer @Ulrike Fishcher

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrike Fischer said, le package showkeys do the job I want.

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys

Thanks again.